# How to reference unrendered dom node using useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So basically I am using a material ui component (Dialog) and whenever I click to open it, the error of:

```
"Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference"
```

I narrowed the issue down to the fact that there is no reference to the node because well it hasn't been rendered yet so the reference is null. The error only occurs once when dialog is first opened so I can be sure thats the reason for the error because after it renders for the first time, there is a reference. Dialog is a modal so of course its null because it won't be rendered until prompted. So how can I get rid of this issue? I am using function based components so I was thinking of using useRef but so far it hasn't solved the issue for me. Here is the Dialog.

```
         <Dialog maxWidth='sm' fullWidth onClose={handleClose} open={commentsOpen}>
            <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className='modalTitle'>
                <Typography align='center' variant="h6">Modal</Typography>
                {handleClose ? (
                <IconButton aria-label="close" className='closeBtn' onClick={handleClose} style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
                ) : null}
            </MuiDialogTitle>
            <MuiDialogContent dividers className='modal'>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <div className='loading'>
                        <CircularProgress style={{ color: 'red' }} />
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <h1>Testing</h1>
                )}
                
            </MuiDialogContent>
            <MuiDialogActions className='modalAction' />
        </Dialog>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Yes, `useRef`, is what you want.  But you will want to mix this with `useEffect`, when useEffect is called the reference will then be valid.

Comment: How would I do so. I tried and I cant nest useRef in useEffect